# notification in background by OneSignal in Swift 3+ without any notification's sign?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background, onesignal

I want to get `JSON` data from push notification in background with [oneSignal](https://onesignal.com) without appears any notification sign in Swift 3+.
my main problem is how to send notification in background for iOS by `OneSignal API`. I did it in Android, but I can't finding any function or method for receive notification's data in Swift.

Comment: did you get any solution because even I am facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the `content_available` parameter to `true` through the OneSignal API. You can use the `data` field to send arbitrary JSON.

When iOS gets this push notification, it will see that content-available is `true`, and it will open your app in the background.

This will only work - however, if the phone is turned on and the user didn't force close your app. But it should work most of the time. Just don't assume that 100% of your userbase will get opened.